# Equal sign changes rendering of legend labels in autoplot of a survfit object

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, survival

I am using the `survival` package to make Kaplan-Mayer estimates of survival curves by group and then I plot out the said curves using packages `ggfortify` and `survminer`. All works fine except the legend labels for plotting. I want to present N sizes of groups in the legend labels. I thought that adding the N size to the grouping variable itself using `paste0` was a good way to go. In my case it is easier than to use something like `scale_fill_discrete("", labels = legend_labeller_for_plot)`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggfortify)


set.seed = 100
data <- data.frame(
  time = rlnorm(20),
  event = as.integer(runif(20) < 0.5),
  group = ifelse(runif(20) > 0.5,
                 "group A",
                 "group B")
)

# Plotting survival curves without N sizes in the legend
fit <- survfit(
  with(data, Surv(time, event)) ~ group,
  data)

autoplot(fit)

# Adding N sizes to the data and plotting
data_new <- data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% mutate(N = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(group_with_N = paste0(group, ", N = ", N))

fit_new <- survfit(
  with(data, Surv(time, event)) ~ group_with_N,
  data_new)

autoplot(fit_new)
```

When I try to add N sizes to the groups variable, the part with "N =" in the grouping variable disappears, i.e. the `group` variable isn't displayed on the legend labels as expected.[image]

For comparison, what I expect is something like the following using Iris data:
[image]

What is more, I found that that the culprit is the equali sign `=`. When I remove the `=` sign, the legend labels correspond to the grouping variable values.
My question is, why does the equal sign cause this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option could be using [ggsurvplot](http://rpkgs.datanovia.com/survminer/reference/ggsurvplot.html) where you can specify the `legend.labs` so you can show your size in the legend like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(survival)
library(survminer)
library(ggfortify)

set.seed = 100
data <- data.frame(
  time = rlnorm(20),
  event = as.integer(runif(20) < 0.5),
  group = ifelse(runif(20) > 0.5,
                 "group A",
                 "group B")
)

# Adding N sizes to the data and plotting
data_new <- data %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% mutate(N = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(group_with_N = paste0(group, ", N = ", N))

fit_new <- survfit(
  with(data, Surv(time, event)) ~ group_with_N,
  data_new)

p <- autoplot(fit_new)
p
```

[image]

```r
# ggsurvplot
ggsurvplot(fit_new, data_new, 
           legend.labs = unique(sort(data_new$group_with_N)),
           conf.int = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>